# Globally handle all exceptions in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2, owin-middleware

I am working in WebApi2. I am going to implement global exception handling. As all we knew, we can use ***IExceptionHandler*** and ***IExceptionLogger*** for the same. I also implemented the same and working fine.

But i am little bit confused with some more scenarios. So I split all my scenarios into 3 parts

### 1. API Exceptions

Here all exceptions in the bound of API need to be handled. Of course, here the rescue is ***IExceptionHandler*** and ***IExceptionLogger*** interfaces. We can implement this and can sent custom HttpResponseMessage from the handler

### 2. Owin Pipeline Exceptions

Here all exception in the owin middleware like token api and all Auth provider level errors.

I read about custom exceptions for middle ware also. But here i need clear suggestion for best practice.

Is this good to create custom middle ware exception or handle in Global.asax?

### 3. Any other Exceptions other than Specified

Here any other exceptions not mentioned above. I don't know exactly, is any other exceptions possible here but i am just thinking about that. If yes, how we need to handle?

Only option is Global.asax Application_Error event. But from this how can i response as HttpResponseMessage with my custom model.

Please give your comments and better way to handle all these exceptions.

**Objective :** *Client didn't get any 500 error with full stack trace. All exceptions will be handled and sent only my custom message to the client*

**Questions :** *How to handle owin pipeline errors and any errors which are not handled in point 1 ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for handling Owin pipeline exception you can write your own ExceptionHandler Middleware and add it to the begining of your owin pipeline. Your middleware can be like this

```
public class GlobalExceptionMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
   public GlobalExceptionMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
   {}

   public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   {
      try
      {
          await Next.Invoke(context);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          // your handling logic
      }
   }
}
```

and also you should write exception handling in Application_Error in case of an exception happened in your handling login in GlobalExceptionMiddleware.

In global.asax in Application_Error you can use `Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject)` to return your custom error.

And also there's no global.asax on `selfhost` so the advantage of having `GlobalExceptionMiddleware` is that if you ever decide to use `SelfHost` instead of IIS, all your exceptions are handled.

Comment: yes. ok but from Application_Error how we return HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: You should use `Response.Write` and `Response.StatusCode`

Comment: ok but i need to respond as json. any help? i will try

Comment: You can use `Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject)` for that, you just need to serialize your object yourself.

Comment: great. i think i am fine now. Please post the same an answer. Only doubt is if i can handle in Application_Error any advantage to create owin middle exception as separate one?